# foreach() not "for eaching" items in array PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

if I do this, it works:

```
$data_array2 = mysql_query("SELECT pic_loc FROM pictures WHERE user_id = '".$id."'");
$cell_pictures = mysql_fetch_array($data_array2);
foreach($cell_pictures as $pics_being_deleted) 
{
unlink($pics_being_deleted);
}
```

Problem being is that the above code is nested meaning it runs a new MySQL query for each time it runs the unlink function so I made the below code to make it not do that:

```
$the_pics_raw_2 = array();
$data_array2 = mysql_query("SELECT pic_loc FROM pictures WHERE user_id = '".$id."'");
while($cell_pictures = mysql_fetch_array($data_array2))
{
$the_pics_raw = $cell_pictures['pic_loc'];
$the_pics_raw_2[] = $the_pics_raw;
}

$the_pics_raw_3 .= " \"../../". implode("\" , \"../../" ,$the_pics_raw_2)."\"";
$the_pics = array($the_pics_raw_3);

foreach($the_pics as $pics_being_deleted) 
{
unlink($pics_being_deleted);
}
```

I get this error in return:

```
Warning: unlink( "../../users/biondizzle/photos/pic_3387677.png" , "../../users/biondizzle/photos/pic_1581185.png") [function.unlink]: No such file or directory
```

it's obviously not going to find the `"../../users/biondizzle/photos/pic_3387677.png" , "../../users/biondizzle/photos/pic_1581185.png"` directory because that's 2 separate directories  running at the same time so the `foreach()` isn't "foreaching".

Any way to get the `unlink()` to run separately for each directory i have listed in the array, I thought I would get it to work by adding the commas and quotations with the `implode()`?
Thanks a bunch, hope I explained it well enough
-Mike

Comment: can you do a var_dump on $the_pics before the foreach loop so that we can see exactly what is being looped?

Comment: Change `$the_pics_raw = $cell_pictures['pic_loc'];` to `$the_pics_raw = '../../'.$cell_pictures['pic_loc'];`, change `$the_pics_raw_2[] = $the_pics_raw;` to `$the_pics[] = $the_pics_raw;` and remove `$the_pics_raw_3 .= " \"../../". implode("\" , \"../../" ,$the_pics_raw_2)."\""; $the_pics = array($the_pics_raw_3);` and your code should work.

Comment: VAR DUMP: array(1) { [0]=> string(98) " "../../users/biondizzle/photos/pic_3387677.png" , "../../users/biondizzle/photos/pic_1581185.png"" }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want to do:

```
while($cell_pictures = mysql_fetch_array($data_array2)) {
    $the_pics_raw = $cell_pictures['pic_loc'];
    $the_pics[] = "../../" . $the_pics_raw;
}

foreach($the_pics as $pics_being_deleted) {
    unlink($pics_being_deleted);
}
```

You will notice I have removed the `$the_pics_raw_3 .= " \"../../". implode("\" , \"../../" ,$the_pics_raw_2)."\"";` line as it was converting the array into a string, which was making it impossible to then `foreach` over.

Comment: Be careful with that whole `" \"../../"` - it should just be `'../../'`

Comment: Heh, yeah just noticed as I was typing up my explanation. Thanks for the spot.

Comment: OHHHH! That makes sense, I get it, thanks so much, this worked great! it won't let me accept the answer for 6 minutes

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
$the_pics_raw = array();
$data_array2 = mysql_query("SELECT pic_loc FROM pictures WHERE user_id = '".$id."'");
while($cell_pictures = mysql_fetch_array($data_array2))
{
array_push($the_pics_raw,"../../".$cell_pictures['pic_loc']);
}

foreach($the_pics as $the_pics_raw) 
{
unlink($pics_being_deleted);
}
```